# Do method calls in derived classes count as virtual function calls?

Tags: c++

Say I have an abstract base class and a derived class like so,

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
}

class Derived: public Base {
private:
    void doSomethingSpecificA();
    void doSomethingSpecificB();
public:
    void doSomething();
}
```

and I initialize my derived class with

```
Base *instance = new Derived;.
```

Now, say I call the derived version of `doSomething` like:

```
instance->doSomething();
```

and `doSomething()` calls the private methods `doSomethingSpecificA()` and `doSomethingSpecificB()`. Do these internal calls to the `specific` functions require the same amount of vtable work that the original call to `doSomething()` required? Or are they equivalent to just a standard method call?

Comment: `doSomethingSpecificA` and `doSomethingSpecificB` are not a virtual functions, there are no entries for them in the vtable in the first place. Calls to them are regular method calls. Inspect the generated assembly, see for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do these internal calls to the specific functions require the same amount of vtable work that the original call to doSomething() required?

No. There is no lookup/dynamic dispatch involved in the calls to `doSomethingSpecificA` and `doSomethingSpecificB` since they are not virtual member functions.

> Or are they equivalent to just a standard method call?

Yes.